# JavaScript .click() unintentionally auto-starting

Tags: javascript

I created a custom variable/function that I am trying to execute when an element is clicked. For some reason, it decides to display onload and ignores the .click(). I've spent a while now trying to figure this out, but I'm not having much luck.

Here's my custom function:

```
var movebox = function (entry) {
    $imagebox.css('left' , '0');
    $('#wr').append(entry);
};
```

I'm attempting to call it like this, but it calls it when the page loads instead.

```
$l3.click(movebox('test'));
```

Answer (score 4):

You're calling the movebox function immediately instead of passing the function as a reference to the click event handler. This is a common mistake in JavaScript. Instead, pass in your function inside of an anonymous function, like so:

```
$l3.click(function() { 
    movebox('test');
});
```

As an aside, the same mistake is oftentimes made with setTimeout, setInterval, addEventListener, and the infamous eval. Remember, when treating functions as arguments to another function, be sure to wrap them in anonymous functions.

Comment: Very helpful! Thanks for the information! I tried this previously without knowing it would work, but it turns out I had a misspelling elsewhere in my code that was making it not work. With this information I double checked my spelling & implemented your fixes and sure enough, works great.

Comment: Was it this:  `$imagebox`?

Comment: $imagebox is fine I think, it's a custom variable I defined previously in the code. I actually had a misspelling in my HTML. I had a long night and name something l2 instead of l3 so the only way I was able to actually see the code working, was when it wasn't working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the `movebox` then passing the returned value to click event handler, in this case you can use the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event registration helper to pass a `data` element to the event handler which can be accessed using the event object.

Try

```
 var movebox = function (e) {
    $imagebox.css('left' , '0');
    $('#wr').append(e.data.entry);
    };

$l3.on('click',{ entry: 'test'}, movebox);
```

Comment: Hi Arun, I'm not the downvoter, but I'm curious. What does this do? Can you explain? Why would we use "on" in this case? As an aside, I can't see why this wouldn't work, even if it might be overkill.

Comment: @jmort253 `on` allows you to pass a data element to the event object see this http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/39MkV/

Comment: I just did this in the JSConsole on this page: `var movebox = function (e) {
    
    console.info(e.data.entry);
    };

$('.bottom-notice').on('click',{ entry: 'test'}, movebox);`. It seems to work, so... +1.  Won't that bind to all future elements matching the selector as well?  If that's what one is looking for, then this is definitely helpful, but if not, it might be a little overkill, depending on the situation. :)

Comment: @jmort253 It will not bind to future elements since you are not using event delegation model for that you have to use `$(document).on('click', '.bottom-notice', { entry: 'test'}, movebox)`

Comment: This works for me as well as the previous suggestion. Also, thanks for the additional information! :)